# Higher-order differentiation of the Implicit Function.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F(x,y)=0$ be an implicit function in terms of $x$ and $y$. Then, if we differentiate both sides with respect to x, we have$${\partial F\over \partial x} \cdot {dx\over dx}+{\partial F\over \partial y} \cdot {dy \over dx}={\partial F\over \partial x}+{\partial F\over \partial y} \cdot {dy \over dx}=0.$$If we rearrange the terms, we have $${dy \over dx}=-{F_x \over F_y}. $$

How could we from here to get the expression ${d^2y \over dx^2}$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $F_x + y'F_y=0$, where $y' = dy/dx$. Now differentiate a second time:
$$F_{xx}x'+F_{xy}y'+y''F_y+y'(F_{xy}x'+F_{yy}y') = 0$$
$$F_{xx}+2y'F_{xy}+(y')^2F_{yy}+y''F_y=0$$
You know that $y'=-F_x/F_y$ and you want to know $y''$. Just substitute and solve.

Comment: Is that a typo? It should be $2y'F_{xy}$.

Comment: @Scorpio19891119 You're right, thanks! In general, it should be

$$(x')^2F_{xx}+2x'y'F_{xy}+(y')^2F_{yy}+x''F_x+y''F_y=0$$

But we know that $x=t$ and so $x' = 1$ and $x''= 0$